# Remove object from List<object> when List contain the same object without creating new list

Tags: c#, linq

I have

```
 var a = new object();
 var b = new object();
 var c = new object();
 var d = new object();
 var e = new object();
 var list = new List<object> {a, b, c, d, e, a, d};
```

Then I need to remove last two objects (`a` and `d`), because they already in the list.
How I can do it without creating new List?

Comment: Is it possible to prevent those objects from being appended to the list in the first place?

Comment: "without creating new List" - what is this constraint really about? Creating a new list isn't an expensive operation in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: There's imho no way with LINQ , because it temporarily creates new lists for every operation to achieve the task. And again there's the question: Why?

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih no, that is incorrect: LINQ does not create a new list for every operation. The only "buffering" operations are things like `OrderBy` and `GroupBy`. Most LINQ-to-Objects operators are streaming APIs

Comment: Gays, I know, that "Creating a new list isn't an expensive operation in the grand scheme of things", but question is: "How I can do it without creating new List?". I read all comments and answer, and  most valuable is @JanesAbouChleih comment. ps. Why you need to know "Why I need to do this"? I have a question, if you have answer - provide it, if haven't don't ask me "why I ask this question".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Why is it suprising that someone doesn't want to create a new  list which requires more memory, hence increases the risk of an `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - it's not surprising, as such, more that it's an unusual requirement. Unusual requirements can frequently come about due to someone misunderstanding some aspect of .NET/C#. So it helps to ask the question (and helps if the person is actually willing to explain their reasoning) because you may be able to provide more *actual* help to the OP if you understand where they're coming from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call `list.Remove` it will remove the *first* instance; you can, however, use `list.RemoveAt` and `list.RemoveRange`. For example:

```
list.RemoveRange(5,2);
```

or better: *don't add them in the first place*.

For example, if you are adding from a sequence you can use `Distinct` or `HashSet<T>` to find unique items when adding.

---

After the fact, you could use:

```
    var dups = from item in list
               group item by item into grp
               where grp.Count() > 1
               select grp.Key;

    foreach (var val in dups)
    {
        int first = list.IndexOf(val), last;
        while ((last = list.LastIndexOf(val)) != first)
        {
            list.RemoveAt(last);
        }
    }
```

To remove all but the first instance of duplicates.

Or perhaps more efficiently:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )
    {
        var val = list[i];
        int first = list.IndexOf(val), last;
        while ((last = list.LastIndexOf(val)) != first)
        {
            list.RemoveAt(last);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But how he would get "2" without any other type of IEnumerable?

Comment: @Tigran which is why (see code above) I'm using `LastIndexOf` - avoids that pain

Comment: Thanks for answer. last part - what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this backwards for-loop and `Enumerable.Contains` + `List.RemoveAt`. This will not create a new list:

```
var list = new List<object> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "d" };
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   var obj = list[i];
   if(list.Take(i).Contains(obj))
       list.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

So this loop gets one object via indexer, takes all objects before it's index and compares it with each other. Note that [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) doesn't create a collection due to it's deferred execution, understood it as a loop, it'll end as soon as [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) returns `true`. If it's already available it will be removed from the list. So the early bird gets the worm.

However, if you want to support custom types you need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your class otherwise `Contains` will just compare the references.

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/mOdeFO)

Comment: already nice answer. Sorry, but I can't accept more then one. Only +1

Answer (score -1):

> How I can do it without creating new List?

You requirement is somewhat surprising (or at least you didn't explain why it is important that the list has to be modified in place), but here is a solution that favors speed of memory usage:

```
var set = new HashSet<object>();
var indicesToRemove = new List<int>();
for (var i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i) {
  var item = list[i];
  if (!set.Contains(item))
    set.Add(item);
  else
    indicesToRemove.Add(i);
}
var itemsRemovedSoFar = 0;
foreach (var i in indicesToRemove) {
  list.RemoveAt(i - itemsRemovedSoFar);
  itemsRemovedSoFar += 1;
}
```

Compare this to a solution where a new list is created:

```
var list = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

I certainly prefer the second solution but it doesn't satisfy you requirement.

Comment: `You requirement is somewhat surprising` Why is it suprising that someone don't want to create a new  list which requires more memory, hence increases the risk of an `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: If the underlying problem is that the source list is very big and should not be duplicated then my solution isn't useful because if the list doesn't have any duplicates the backing storage of the `HashSet` will consume the same amount of storage as the source list. However, even though some of the other proposed solutions doesn't consume more memory they are very inefficient in terms of CPU required because the repeatedly search the source list for duplicates. This solution avoids this inefficiency by using more memory.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that there's a good reason to avoid duplicating collections even if the backing collections are temporary. It might be unimportant if the program needs a few seconds more(e.g. if it's a windows-service) but it's probably important that it runs without an exception. Also, if the loop approach is inefficient against the hashset it would mean that the collection is really large. Then the memory issue is even more important.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Completely agree. My solution is not good if the source is very large and memory is a concern. However, why the list was to be modified in place was not specified in the question. Another possible reason could be that some third party API was involved making it impossible to replace the list.